# iOS Bar Item image displaying wrong color

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a bar with Bar Items, my .png image has green color, but when i add it to storyboard it's displaying as blue.

How can i make it display the image as it is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to set `tintColor` sometimes it helps me to set the actual color of image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage:style:target:action:) are a little ambiguous about this

> The images displayed on the bar are derived from this image. If this
>   image is too large to fit on the bar, it is scaled to fit. Typically,
>   the size of a toolbar and navigation bar image is 20 x 20 points. The
>   alpha values in the source image are used to create the images—opaque
>   values are ignored.

Essentially what this is saying is the image you supply will not be what is actually displayed. Instead the system uses the alpha mask of the image and the `tintColor` of the item to generate the final display.

Comment: Re-read my answer, it is used in conjunction with the `tintColor` of the item, try setting that to green. If you want more than a single, solid colour you would need to use other approaches (see [Ishan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32738140/2613662))

Answer (score 3):

Use `tintColor` of UIBarButton to set the desired color for the image.
If its absolutely necessary to use original image colors, use this to set the image:

```
[aBarButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Answer (score 2):

add image programmatically

```
[button setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]   imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

if its not work then try this:-

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFile.png"];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuObject:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

if its not work then try this:-

```
#define setTurqoiseColor [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0f/255.0f green:181.0f/255.0f blue:223.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]

UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:buttonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self  action:@selector(toggleMenu)];
menuButton.tintColor = setTurqoiseColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

To set tint color of bar item global, in your App Delegate, add these lines of code

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearance];
[barButtonAppearance setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // set to your color
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your UITabBar tintColor.

[image]

If you would like to add a custom color / gradient you can set your tabBarItem image and selectedImage property as follow:

```
 customTabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "customSelectedImage")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
 customTabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "customUnselectedImage")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```