# Set custom images to the UIBarButtonItem but it doesn't show any image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to set custom images to the UIBarButtonItem but it only shows a rectangular box around and It doesn't show the actual image.

```
func setupBrowserToolbar() {
    let browser = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 30))
    //配置返回组件
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("back", ofType: "png")
    let urlstr = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlstr)
    let btnback = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(data: data!), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("backClicked:"))
    //分割按钮1
    let btngrap1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    //前进按钮
    let btnforward = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "forward.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("forwardClicked:"))
    //分割按钮2
    let btngrap2 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    //重新加载
    let btnreload = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "reload.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("reloadClicked:"))
    //分割按钮3
    let btngrap3 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    //停止加载
    let btnstop = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"stop.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("stopClicked:"))
    progress = UIProgressView((frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 48, width: self.view.frame.width-50, height: 2)))
    progress.progress = 0
    browser.setItems([btnback, btngrap1, btnforward, btngrap2, btnreload, btngrap3, btnstop], animated: true)
    ptimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("loadProgress"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    self.view.addSubview(browser)
}
```

[my app screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkOkZ.png)

The above method is toolbar configuration but I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because UIBarButtonItem image's default rendering mode always draw the image as a template image, ignoring its color information (UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate). Just create your image using UIImage's method imageWithRenderingMode always original.

```
UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help, could you tell me how do you know, I don't see this information in the official website of the description.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage:style:target:action:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32738254/2303865 you should also take a look at this one

Comment: The alpha values in the source image are used to create the images—opaque values are ignored.This sentence mean, the picture will be fully transparent, and then, just now you recommend me an article, it will use the tint color to fill the picture completely transparent part, is that right?

Comment: @XIAOHANG yes by default it will use the alpha and the tint color. if you need to change its color or size you need to use the rendering always original

Comment: one last link that might help you preparing your images http://stackoverflow.com/a/29874619/2303865

Comment: I have a problem Can you help me?

Comment: @XIAOHANG sure. Sorry for the delay your message got lost in the middle of them all. Whats is your problem if you still have it?

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3 , 4 update

From swift 3, the method is changed to the following format

```
UIImage(named:"yourImageName")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```