# ImageWithRenderingMode AlwaysOriginal not working on UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

Instead of using the tint color to indicate when a tab is selected, I just want to use the original images. These are the images I'm using:

Default: [image: Default]

Selected: [image: Selected]

I added the images in the Storyboard, and in my code to setup the TabBarController I have the following:

```
let manageItem = tabBar.items?[1]
manageItem?.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
manageItem?.selectedImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

But every time I build and run, I'm still getting the blue color when selected. Also, it seems to be altering the selected image. Here's what it looks like:

Not selected (second tab):

[image: Unselected Screen shot]

Selected:

[image: Selected screen shot]

Why is it not using the original images?

Comment: You need to set the UImage rendering mode, not the button image property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34101842/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I recall `imageWithRenderingMode` returns new image, so you should rather use it like this :

```
let manageItem = tabBar.items?[1]
manageItem?.image = manageItem?.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
manageItem?.selectedImage = manageItem?.selectedImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: @internetdotcom seeing as the question and answer are both from 2016, then this is around iOS 9.