# How do I use custom images for TabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift

Right now, I'm using black/white pngs as my icons, and using tintColor when user selects them.  I feel that this is too plain.

I want to use multi-color images (it's selected) and then a grey-scale version of the same image (when it's not selected)

How do I use two images for each TabBar Item?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34101842/2303865

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737907/ios-bar-item-image-displaying-wrong-color/32738254?s=2|0.6965#32738254

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of your `UITabBarController` and set the icon images to `UITableBarItem`s in `viewDidLoad()` of `UITabBarController` subclass.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let tabBar: UITabBar = self.tabBar
    let tabBarItem1: UITabBarItem = tabBar.items![0]
    let tabBarItem2: UITabBarItem = tabBar.items![1]

    tabBarItem1.image = UIImage.init(named: "tab_icon_1_normal")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem2.image = UIImage.init(named: "tab_icon_2_normal")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "tab_icon_1_selected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "tab_icon_2_selected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
}
```